# What game is this die from?

Tags: identify-this-game, dice

I have found a die. The faces depict Fire, a Sheep, a Lock, a Footprint, an "L", and a Magnet.

What game is it from?

Comment: Do you have a picture of the die or can you take one? Providing one would probably greatly help with identifying it.

Answer (score 16):

Could it be one of

### [Rory's Story Cubes](http://www.storycubes.com/)

?

[image: Story Cube]
[image: Story Cube Box]

After looking closely at those photos, I'm going to say definitively, why yes. Yes it could:

- In the top photo, the front right die has an [L] and a fire facing the camera.
- In the bottom photo, the die in the top right of the box art depicts a single die with a magnet, sheep, and footprint on three sides.

SQB points out in comments these are in fact the same die, with a lock on the side these photos don't show, so it matches the description of the die you found precisely.

Comment: I took out my copy and I can confirm that the standard set includes such a die. It's visible in the second picture, in the upper right of the box, showing the footprint, sheep, and magnet. It's in the first picture as well, in the foreground on the right, showing the 'L' and the fire.